# Montar RegEx para validar senha

Tags: javascript, regex, validação, senhas

alguem saberia montar um regex para validar sequencias numéricas e alfabéticas de no minimo 4 digitos, tipo : 1111/1234/abcd/4321/dcba?

Comment: Você quer validar se são sequências ou iguais? Não entendi muito bem.

Comment: quero validar os dois, por exemplo, se o cara escrever "1111", não posso autorizar essa senha por serem digitos iguais, se for "1234" ou "abcd" também não posso, eu não sei usar regEx, eu tinha feito por valores de uma array, mas vi que nas boas praticas o ideal é usar regEx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mínimo 4 caracteres, pelo menos 1 letra e 1 número:

```
"^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{4,}$"
```

Comment: cara tentei aqui  e não funcionou muito bem, achei um que funcionou um pouco melhor "^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?!.*[\W_\x7B-\xFF]).{4,15}$"

Comment: Ok, se você achou uma que serve melhor, ótimo, a idéia é vc conseguir solucionar o seu problema. Abraço.

Answer (score 3):

Se você quer validar se a senha possui 4 caracteres contendo letras ou números apenas. Pode usar essa Regex:

```
^[^\W_]{4}$
```

Caso queira testar, eu recomendo esse site: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score -3):

```
private string getRegex()
    {
        string regex = "^.*(?=.{" + this.TamanhoMinimo.ToString() + ","+this.TamanhoMaximo.ToString()+"})";


        if (SenhaForte)
        {
            regex += "(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])";
            if (this.CaracterEspecial)
            {
                regex += "(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            regex += "(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9@#$%^&+=])";
        }

        regex += ".*$";

        return regex;
    }

//Letras maiúsculas, minusculas, caracteres especiais (@#$%^&+=) e numeros.
```

Comment: http://www.codigoexpresso.com.br/Home/Postagem/52

Comment: Isso ai não parece javascript, e a tag da pergunta é JAVASCRIPT.